# MoviePy: How to convert horizontal video to vertical

Tags: video, moviepy

I have the following 1920x1080 video:
[image]

I need to convert it to 1080x1920, and zoom in in the center so that it looks like this:

[image]

by using moviepy. I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find video rotation and rotate the clip accordingly using moviepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200027/how-can-i-find-video-rotation-and-rotate-the-clip-accordingly-using-moviepy)

Comment: @Tranbi I don't think the issue is rotation. I just need 1920 video to get different dimensions without it being compressed

Answer (score 5):

this works fine (from 1920x1080 to 1080x1920):

```
video = video.resize(height=1920)
video = video.crop(x1=1166.6,y1=0,x2=2246.6,y2=1920)
```

Comment: may I ask how did you get the x1 and x2 values?
for me, the values made the crop alittle off-center (alittle too much to the right)