# MoviePy: How to convert horizontal 1920x1080 video to vertical 1080x1920 video?

Tags: moviepy

I am trying to convert a horizontal video clip (1920x1080) using Moviepy to a vertical video clip (1080x1920), and also understand the Moviepy Docs.

The docs say x1,y1 is the upper left corner and x2,y2 is the bottom right corner. But when I enter the numbers, the videos are cropped either too much to the left or too much to the right.

I tried:

```
final_clip = final_clip.resize(height=1920)
final_clip = final_clip.crop(x1=0,y1=1920,x2=1080,y2=0)
```

But the result is it would say it is writing the file, but the file disappears after the progress bar finishes.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69339396/moviepy-how-to-convert-horizontal-video-to-vertical), but my results are alittle too much to the right.

I tried:

```
resize(height=1920)
crop(x_center=960,width=1080,height=1920)
```

and the result seems like x_center is where the right side of the frame is cropped.

Am I missing the basics of movie coordinates or something? The whole thing seems a mess to me...

Answer (score 1):

After many trial and error, I find the following method works:

```
resize(height=1920)
crop(x_center=960, y_center=960, width=1080, height=1920)
```